# Printing contents of xlsx sheet

Tags: java, eclipse, docx4j, import-from-excel

I'm using docx4j in eclipse to get the contents of an excel sheet but all what I'm getting is numbers. For simplicity, assume this is my sheet:

### | asd | sd |

### | hgn |

The code I'm using to load the contents is:

```
public static void load(String outputfilepath) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try {
        SpreadsheetMLPackage exc = SpreadsheetMLPackage
                .load(new java.io.File(outputfilepath));
        WorksheetPart sheet = exc.getWorkbookPart().getWorksheet(0);
        System.out.println(sheet.getPartName().getName());
        Worksheet ws = sheet.getJaxbElement();
        SheetData data = ws.getSheetData();
        int ic = 0;
        for (Row r : data.getRow()) {
            System.out.println("row " + ic);
            int ir = 0;
            for (Cell c : r.getC()) {
                System.out.println("cell " + ir + " contains "
                        + c.getV().toString());
                ir++;
            }
            ic++;
        }
        System.out.println("\ndone");
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Xlsx4jException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
row 0
cell 0 contains 0
cell 1 contains 1
row 1
cell 0 contains 2

done
```

What should I do to get the actual content?

Note: The problem occurs only with strings. ie if there are numbers in a cell I get them without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within XLSX the text contents of the cells is not stored directly in the sheet XML. There is a `sharedStrings.xml` in the XLSX archive.

Thats why `docx4j` does not read the text content with `getV()` but the index of this content in the `sharedStrings.xml`. So you have the index and can get the content from the sharedStrings.

See example: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/xlsx4j/org/xlsx4j/samples/PartsList.java

```
...
for (Cell c : r.getC() ) {
 if (c.getT().equals(STCellType.S)) {
  System.out.println( "  " + c.getR() + " contains " + sharedStrings.getJaxbElement().getSi().get(Integer.parseInt(c.getV())).getT() );
 } else {
  // TODO: handle other cell types
  System.out.println( "  " + c.getR() + " contains " + c.getV() );
 }
}
...
```

Note you have to read first the `RelationshipsPart` to get the `sharedStrings`. This is done in that example within the `public static void printInfo(Part p, StringBuilder sb, String indent)` while traversing the relationships in `public static void traverseRelationships`.

Numbers and formulas are directly stored in the sheet XML. So for those contents the `getV()` will get the content directly.

Comment: Thanks! It worked and the example is useful. Just a small note, this line `System.out.println( "  " + c.getR() + " contains " + sharedStrings.getJaxbElement().getSi().get(Integer.parseInt(c.getV())).getT());` returns the memory address of the string, to get the value of the string just add `.getValue()`.